# Why can I not access members of the base class without casting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, casting

Let's say I have a `System.Web.IHttpHandler` whose base class is `ASP.login_aspx` whose base class is `MyCMS.Admin.Login` whose base class is... etc... all the way back to `System.Web.UI.Page` and of course, `object`.

Why do I have to cast my IHttpHandler as `MyCMS.Admin.Login` before I can access the members of that type and below?

Example:

```
IHttpHandler result = base.GetHandler(context, requestType, virtualPath, path);
bool isVisible = result.Visible;//Does not work
bool isVisible = ((MyCMS.Admin.Login)(result)).Visible;//Works
//Noting that Visible is a member of System.Web.UI.Page
```

For clarity, I'm not expecting that result.Visible *should* work, I just want to know why it doesn't.

Comment: See the FAQ regarding signatures in posts.

Comment: I think you have the inheritance tree backwards. `base` classes are the parents (meaning the ones included after the `:` in a class definition).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Visible` is not a member of `IHttpHandler`, so you should not expect to be able to call it on such a variable. It's a member of `Page`, by way of `Control`, I believe.

When you cast a variable to one of the base types/interfaces of the object's class, you can only call members that are on the type of the *variable* (or base classes/interfaces of *that* type).

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up Andrew, that (and your other comments) actually makes a lot of sense now! So basically, if we use the example above, you can assign any object to `result` as long as it implements `IHttpHandler`, but in order to access the object's members, you must cast it to something. Is that correct?

Comment: First part is correct: You can assign any reference to result that implements `IHttpHandler`, yes. But you don't have to cast it to anything else in order to use the members of `IHttpHandler`... primarily, `ProcessRequest()`, for example. `IHttpHandler` is a very sparse interface; it only defines ProcessRequest and IsReusable. See Bernard's answer for a link to the reference of IHttpHandler.

Comment: Fabulous, I get it! Thanks so much for your help. It was the clarification of your answer that helped most.

Answer (score 1):

The [IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) interface is just that - an interface. It has no knowledge of a `Visible` member since any class can implement this interface. What you ended up doing is casting to an object of a class that does inherit the `Visible` member.

Comment: To be clear, this is not because IHttpHandler is an interface; it's because that interface doesn't happen to have a member called Visible.

Comment: Good answer. I've been sporadically working with C# for a while now, but being self-taught, there's still foundational knowledge I'm lacking. Particularly with respect to interfaces. Can you explain please why `result.GetType().BaseType` returns `MyCMS.Admin.Login`?

Comment: @IainFraser Because `GetType()` returns the `Type` that the *object* is; not that the *variable* is. But you can only call members that are on the type of the *variable*.